# How can I choose which SID from a SC 2 server will be played?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, shoutcast

My code looks like the following and everything works fine

```
public void ibutton_play_stop_click(View v)
{
    switch(sharedPrefs.getInt("quality", 1))
    {
        case 0:
        {
            uriStationURL = Uri.parse(StaticVars.RadioStations[0]);
            break;
        }
        case 1:
        {
            uriStationURL = Uri.parse(StaticVars.RadioStations[1]);
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            uriStationURL = Uri.parse(StaticVars.RadioStations[2]);
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            uriStationURL = Uri.parse(StaticVars.RadioStations[3]);
            break;
        }
    }       
    try
    {           
        if((player == null) || (!player.isPlaying()))
        {
            this.player = new MediaPlayer();
            prgBrBuffer.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);
            player.stop();
            player.reset(); 
            player.setDataSource(this, uriStationURL);
            player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            player.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
            player.setOnErrorListener(this);
            player.prepareAsync();
            ibttnPlayStop.setEnabled(false);
        }
        else if((player != null) && (player.isPlaying()))
        {
            player.stop();
            player.reset();         
            player = null;
        }

    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        Log.e("Media Player Error: ", e.toString());
    }
}
```

but regardless of the choosen "?sid=" every time the same stream is being played.

My question is now: how can i choose which of the given sid from my shoutcast2 server is being played from my media player?

Comment: may be ur mediaplayer is not refreshed ..it seems so from ur problem statement

Comment: I edited it with my full code. As you can see I reload the full player every time

Answer (score 1):

Do not use server.address/?sid=x, instead just use server.address/x

Comment: Tried your solution, but still the same issue

Comment: Apologies, mea culpa. You cannot get directly to the actual stream via the numeric id of the stream. What you can do though is fetch the relative playlist file by getting server.address/listen.pls?sid=x , then parse the output and get the address that is listed in the entry **File1=**  This will give you the actual mountpoint name of the stream (i.e. server.address:port/streamname)